# Use matplotlib to plot the functions $y = x^3 + 3x^2 - x + 0.3\ $ and $y = \sin x$

Tags: graphing-functions, math-software, python

I'm new to Python coding and wondered if someone could give me the coding to plot these two graphs on the same program.

This is what I have so far, exactly as typed on Python, however I know that parts are incorrect.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

x = [float(i)/100 for i in range(0,101)]
y = [sin(x)]

plt.plot(x,y)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need a larger range for $x$ to see a nice sinusoid, say from $0$ to $2\pi$.
Second, specify $y$ as a list comprehension, too:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import math

x = [float(i)/100 for i in range(0, 628)]
y = [math.sin(z) for z in x]

plt.plot(x,y)
```

[image]

---

If you want to plot *both* graphs one over the other (what isn't generally a good idea because those 2 function are so different, that in the default settings the sine function will appear as to coincide with the x-axis), the code may be as follows (I extended the range for $x$, and set limits for $y$-axes):

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import math

BOUND = 1000

x = [float(i)/100 for i in range(-BOUND, +BOUND)]
y = [math.sin(z) for z in x]
w = [z**3 + 3*z**2 - z + 0.3 for z in x]


plt.ylim(-7,+7)
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.plot(x, w)
```

[image]

Comment: Ah I see, so how would I add the second y graph onto this?

Comment: Do you mean to overlay this graph, or to create other  one (in the other window)?

Comment: They will both be on the same axis so it will over lay it and show both

Comment: It's not a good idea, because there is such difference between the 2 functions that the sine function will appear to coincident with x axis. See: $\sin(5\pi /2) = 1$, while $x^3 + 3x^2 - x + 0.3$ will be for the same $x =5\pi /2$ approximately $662$.

Comment: That what the assignment question is asking me to do as I am to find the real solutions of the graphs.

Comment: @Brooke, I extended my answer to satisfy your requirements.

Comment: Thank you much appreciated!